# Replacing a href element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to change part of the link.

Exactly I have to change "/?" to "/all?" in every a href on the site.

I was reading something about that, but nothing works.

Can you help me?

Greetings.

Comment: [What did you try](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: yea, but replace function give me only errors and I dont have idea how to do this, im newbie with Javascript and jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('a').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('/?', '/all?'))
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/w9E8m/)**

Comment: TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of null

i've got still this error

My website is on Magento platform and my jquery version is 1.4.2

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is being included?

Comment: You should really look at the docs, there are some interesting overloaded version of some of these simple functions (which avoids using an `.each`) ;)

Answer (score 1):

This solution you wont need jQuery, i'm also assuming you desire to change every match of /? in your URL, if not, use only **replace('/?','/all?')**

JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/eZgmD/

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
for (var i = 0; i<anchors.length; i++)
{
      anchors[i].href = anchors[i].href.replace(/\/\?/g,'/all?') 
};
```

Comment: Regex is overkill for a simple string replace.

Comment: He didnt say it was in one place of the URL

Comment: And when would the second instance of an unescaped `?` occur (obviously notwithstanding invalid uris)?

Comment: Brad, I got your point. And also edited the article refering to a simple replace approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').attr('href', function(){
    return this.href.replace('/?', '/all?');
});
```

[`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) can be passed a function as the assigning argument.

Answer (score 0):

To change the href on a link you use this Jquery function:

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
```

Where the web site is changed to what you want to overwrite on the href attribute.